# Android Navigation and setResult

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation

An activity that resides in a different lib is closed via close or ok button click.
Inside the button handlers a result is set like this

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("Parameters", json);

Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtras(b);
setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, data);

finish();
```

In an older app this activity was called using getResultFromActivity.

The app I am currently working on should use this activity and get the results from it.
My problem is, that my app is using the navigation component and I can't figure out how to receive the values from the activity with that.
From what I've read so far, the Activity Result API is the way to go. But I don't understand how to use is. Especially where to use it. Where/when do I register for the activity results?

The lib is a bit older, but for different reasons I don't want to rewrite it right now.
Is it possible to use it with the navigation component, preferably without changing the lib?

Comment: Doesn't look promising... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702643/equivalent-of-startactivityforresult-with-android-architecture-navigation